# php arrays and mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is driving me nuts! I need to fill up and HTML table with values that I pulled out from a DB.
The HTML table has 100  one td for each value.

I have an array that I populate doing this:

```
$x = 1;
$ArrayA = array();
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
        $ArrayA[$x] = 0;
    }
```

So now I have an array with 100 values, right?

Then I query my DB, and get the result that I "want"
(select num from table1)
6 rows with the following values:
`1,3,14,50,100.`

Then I insert the values from my query into the $ArrayA that I populated before with one hundred 0's

```
$x = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
    extract($row);
    $ArrayA[$x] = "$num";
        $x++;   
}
```

Now `$ArrayA` has this:
`1,3,14,17,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.....`

And my goal is to replace with a `0` where I should have a "next" number, hard to explain..
I need this result:
`1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,0,0,17,0....`

I tried to use PHP `array_splice`, but it did not work.
I tried with some if statements but my logic and programing experience is not that good.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I tried like 10 times to format my code using the code editor and I couldn't, sorry.

Comment: So, if you get a value from the DB of 12, you replace the 12th array element with 12? Why not something like $ArrayA[dbvalue] = dbvalue? Are you sure though, that you will not pull a number from the db that is greater than the upper bound of your array? The other way you could do it is to do your query, then do your for loop to populate the array, and use an if statement, if (array index in list of dbvalues) replace array element with db value, else replace with 0.

Comment: +1 for confusing the sh!+ out of me!

Comment: I think I understand what he wants, but I have no clue why he wants it that way.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you want for your second code block:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    extract($row);
    if($num > 0 && $ <= 100 )
    {
        $ArrayA[$num] = "$num";
    } 
}
```

If your DB values are 3, 10, 15, 22, 100, you'd end up with 0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,15, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this right, you want to add a zero after every element returned by your query? Right? If so, why not add a zero right after you add an element into the array?

```
$x = 1; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))      {

extract($row);     
$ArrayA[$x] = "$num";       
$x++;
$ArrayA[$x] = "0"; //adds zero after every $num insert    
}
```

Maybe you can clarify if this isn't what you're asking...

Answer (score 0):

```
$match_rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$rows = range(1,100);

    foreach( $rows as $row){

    echo '<td>';

        if( in_array($row, $match_rows) ){
        echo $row;
        }else{
        echo 0;
        }

    echo '</td>' . PHP_EOL; 

    }
```

Sorry, that is untested - it could be shorter or neater, but like that possibly illustrates another way of achieving what you want.